# Call ApplicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: objective-c, xcode, save, appdelegate, shutdown

I want to call ApplicationDidEnterBackground.
I use this code in my MainViewController.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_savedText];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"savedText"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

But I think it's never called. I tried to put the content in app delegate, but then I get errors because it can't find "_savedText". Do I need to import "_savedText" to app delegate or should I do otherwise?

Comment: Is there this definition: `MainViewController: UIViewController < UIApplicationDelegate >`?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in it to see if it is called.

Comment: Now I have tried to put a breakpoint in it. It is called in appDelegate but not called in MainViewController. The definition look like this: MainViewController : UITableViewController

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access other Class instance from AppDelegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395159/access-other-class-instance-from-appdelegate)

Answer (score 0):

`-applicationDidEnterBackground:` is a part of the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol. It is a message which the application will send to the application delegate. Implementing a method with the same name on some other class, a view controller in this case, will not cause it to be called.

If you need a view controller to react to the application entering the background you could subscribe the to the [`UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:) notification via a notification center.

However if a controller needs to know about application-wide events like this then I suspect that controller is responsible for too many concerns and you might want to consider how it could be simplified.